# Vírgula com vários adjuntos

Tags: pontuação, advérbios, vírgula

Alguém poderia me informar como pontuar corretamente esta frase?

"eu viajo em média uma vez por semana quando estou trabalhando e até duas vezes por semana quando estou de férias"

Estava lendo um livro traduzido do inglês que havia várias vírgulas nessa frase... omiti todas para não enviesar a resposta... poderiam por favor me ajudar a colocar as vírgulas nessa frase e também a origem de cada regra gramatical que implica no uso ou não da vírgula entre cada parte da frase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu pontuaria assim:

> Eu viajo, em média, uma vez por semana quando estou trabalhando, e até duas vezes por semana quando estou de férias.

Lembre-se, no entanto, de que esta não é a única possibilidade. Tudo depende do estilo. No caso, estou usando a expressão "em média" entre vírgulas para destacá-la, para dar uma certa entonação à frase pelo uso das pausas (vírgulas identificam pausas). Mas você poderia optar por não usar estas vírgulas e dizer simplesmente

> Eu viajo em média uma vez por semana quando estou trabalhando, e até duas vezes por semana quando estou de férias.

Como mencionei, é questão de estilo. O que você NÃO pode fazer é usar somente uma vírgula. Seriam formas incorretas de usar a vírgula com uma expressão explicativa como "em média":

> Eu viajo, em média uma vez por semana ...

ou

> Eu viajo em média, uma vez por semana ...

A vírgula do trecho abaixo se justifica já que "e" no caso não é uma adição ao fato anterior e sim uma contraposição.

> quando estou trabalhando, e até duas vezes

Sua pergunta é muito boa, pois textos com excesso de vírgulas podem ficar mais difíceis de serem compreendidos. Ao usar vírgulas, faça-o com cuidado! Use-as, pois são úteis, fundamentais, mas não exagere!

Comment: e porque devo utilizar a virgula antes do "e" ?

Comment: Porque é a segunda oração não é uma adição, não complementa a oração anterior, e sim, se contrapõe. A primeira oração apresenta um dado (duas vezes) em uma situação (quando estou trabalhando) - enquanto a segunda oração refere-se a uma situação diferente (quando estou em férias) ... assim este “e” não é “aditivo”, ele oferece uma informação alternativa.

Answer (score 1):

Eu pontuaria assim:

> — Eu viajo, em média, uma vez por semana, quando estou trabalhando, e até duas vezes por semana, quando estou de férias.

Explicação:

- as vírgulas em torno de "em média" separam a expressão explicativa;
- as antes dos "quando"s são opcionais, dado que se tem a ordem canônica, e, normalmente, eu não virgularia, mas aqui a oração me parece ter um caráter restritivo/explicativo;
- a antes do "e", já que ele tem caráter adversativo e não aditivo (poderia ser substituído por "mas").